# Python random.choice() fails to work in a function

Tags: python, random

I'm having trouble getting Pythons random.choice to work

Here's the working code:

```
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Password Generator")
user_amount_letters = int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
user_amount_symbols = int(input("How many symbols?\n"))
user_amount_numbers = int(input("How many numbers\n"))

characters = []

for i in range(user_amount_letters):
  characters.append(random.choice(letters))
for i in range(user_amount_numbers):
  characters.append(random.choice(numbers))
for i in range(user_amount_symbols):
  characters.append(random.choice(symbols))

random.shuffle(characters)
password = "".join(characters)
print(password)
```

Here's the same code within a function:

```
.
.
.
def randomise_user_password(letters, symbols, numbers):
  user_letters = letters
  user_symbols = symbols
  user_numbers = numbers
  characters = []
  
  for i in range(user_letters):
    characters.append(random.choice(letters))
  for i in range(user_numbers):
    characters.append(random.choice(numbers))
  for i in range(user_symbols):
    characters.append(random.choice(symbols))

  random.shuffle(characters)
  password = "".join(characters)
  return password


print(randomise_user_password(user_amount_letters, user_amount_symbols, user_amount_numbers))
```

The problem seems to be with random.choice, heres the error for reference:

```
3.8.12/lib/python3.8/password_generator.py", line 288, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I understand what the error is telling me, but have no clue how to resolve it.

Comment: You have a `letters` within the function & a `letters` outside the function (supposedly) with seemingly different jobs.

Comment: `user_amount_letters` `user_amount_symbols` and `user_amount_numbers` are integers, which are passed to the function, so inside the function this parameters are called `letters, symbols, numbers`  but the random function requires a list to choose, not an int

Comment: Just a side note: You can generate your alphabet lists much more efficiently if you use `chr()` with list comprehension and an ASCII table. This returns the same `letters` list that you typed manually `[chr(x) for x in list(range(65,91))+list(range(97,123))]`

Comment: @picobit or even easier  `string.ascii_letters` and `string.digits`  https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

Comment: Thanks guys, it all works nicely now. It completely slipped my mind about the list names. Also @picobit thanks for the suggestion, that looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments of your method are named the same as your lists.

Just change up the names of your lists like this:

```
import random
lettersList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbersList = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbolsList = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

user_amount_letters = int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
user_amount_symbols = int(input("How many symbols?\n"))
user_amount_numbers = int(input("How many numbers\n"))

def randomise_user_password(letters, symbols, numbers):
    user_letters = letters
    user_symbols = symbols
    user_numbers = numbers
    characters = []

    for i in range(user_letters):
        characters.append(random.choice(lettersList))
    for i in range(user_numbers):
        characters.append(random.choice(numbersList))
    for i in range(user_symbols):
        characters.append(random.choice(symbolsList))

    random.shuffle(characters)
    password = "".join(characters)
    return password


print(randomise_user_password(user_amount_letters, user_amount_symbols, user_amount_numbers))
```

> Input: 5 5 5

> Output: mHEWsvmnYxfGQcu

Comment: How about removing `user_letters = letters` (and the other two) and adjusting the code to use the named parameters. There is no  reason for the assignment and the example would be better without them.

Comment: Yes, even better. There is no need to assign the arguments to another variable in the first place. But still the arguments (or the lists for that matter) need their name changed as to avoid doubling.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters of the function letters, symbols, numbers are named like the arrays. So you are trying to make a random choice of a int. Pas by parameter the list of letters, symbols, numbers too.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

lettersList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbersList = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbolsList = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

user_amount_letters = int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
user_amount_symbols = int(input("How many symbols?\n"))
user_amount_numbers = int(input("How many numbers\n"))

def randomise_user_password():
    password = []
    for i in range(0, user_amount_letters):
        password.append(random.choice(lettersList))
    for i in range(0, user_amount_symbols):
        password.append(random.choice(symbolsList))
    for i in range(0, user_amount_numbers):
        password.append(random.choice(numbersList))
    random.shuffle(password)
    password = "".join(password)
    return password

print(randomise_user_password())
```

****Input****

> 3 letters, 2 symbols, 3 numbers

****Outputs****

> wAp8*53$